# Java - implementing Runnable acts different compared to extending Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm trying to learn how multithreading works. This is the example code I have:

```
public class Processor extends Thread {
    private boolean running = true;

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Hello there!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void shutDown() {
        running = false;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class ProcessorDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Processor proc1 = new Processor();
        proc1.start();

        System.out.println("Press return to stop");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.nextLine();
        proc1.shutDown();

    }

}
```

The problem occurs, when I implement Runnable instead of extending Thread - the code difference

```
public class Processor implements Runnable

// in ProcessorDemo
Thread proc1 = new Thread(new Processor());
```

What happens is, the code gives an error, saying:
"The method shutDown() is undefined for the type Thread"

Why is this happening, when both ways of creating Threads should give the same result?

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: This is a highly environment/language specific question. Please include that information in your question. Preferably in tags.

Comment: _"both ways of creating Threads should give the same result"_ -- this is incorrect.  Why do you think this is true?

Comment: Did you mean to say your second version doesn't compile at all? This is not quite 'acts different' since one doesn't act at all as you never run it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't compile, because the java.lang.Thread class doesn't have a `shutDown()` method defined on it; that was a method that you defined yourself on the `Processor` class.

Take a careful look at which methods are available on a plain `java.lang.Thread` at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html.  If you want to stop a thread, I would suggest looking at `.interrupt()` or `.join()` depending on your particular needs.

An example of how you might use `.interrupt()`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread proc1 = new Thread(new Processor());
        proc1.start();

        System.out.println("Press return to stop");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.nextLine();
        proc1.interrupt();

    }
}

class Processor implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (! Thread.interrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Hello there!");
        }
    }
}
```

I usually implement the `Runnable` interface myself instead of subclassing `Thread`, but you'll have to think about which one makes more sense for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, class `Processor` is defined to have a method `shutdown`. Therefore when instantiating `Processor`, the method exists.

In the second example, `shutdown` exists under class `Processor`, while you are trying to invoke it on class `Thread`.

In this example, class `Thread` was never extended, and as such doesn't have any additional functionality like the extended class `Thread` (`Processor`) in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

In First case, You intialized your reference with type 'Processor'. Since, Class Processor have the method 'shutDown()'. JVM could find the method in class processor.
    Processor proc1 = new Processor();

In second case while 'Processor implementing Runnable'. You initialized the object 'proc1' using type 'Thread'. Wheares the type 'Thread' do not have the method 'Shutdown'. Only your class 'Processor' have the method 'shutdown()'

That's why while trying to invoke 'proc1.shutDown()' you are getting error as 'method undefined' --> Which actually means, Method 'shutDown()' is not available in Class 'Thread'

```
Processor proc1 = new Processor();
Thread proc1 = new Thread(proc1);
proc1.shutDown();
```

Comment: so how can i use it while implementing?

Comment: added the code in answer. Replace that set in your main method. it will work

Answer (score 0):

**Problem in Second example:**
 Remember your are using `Thread` instance to invoke the method `shutDown()` which actually present in your `Processor` class.

But this is not the case in **your first example**. You used `Processor` instance to invoke `shutDown()` which is legal.